# Use of a RadInputManager (telerik)

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-radinput

i'm trying to use this control to check a time (HH:MM) a user inserts...

This is what i'm using but not working

```
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtEstimation" runat="server">
            </telerik:RadTextBox>
            <telerik:RadInputManager ID="RadInputManager1" runat="server">
                <telerik:RegExpTextBoxSetting EmptyMessage="EmptyMessage" ValidationExpression="(([01][0-9])|(2[0-3])):[0-5][0-9]"
                    ErrorMessage="*">
                    <TargetControls>
                        <telerik:TargetInput ControlID="txtEstimation" />
                    </TargetControls>
                </telerik:RegExpTextBoxSetting>
            </telerik:RadInputManager>
```

I was inspired by this : http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-inputmanager-basics.html
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what does it mean 'not working'? not working as expected, it generates js errors or it throws server errors?

Comment: Not working as expected... i would like this textbox to only allow the user to enter something of this format : HH:MM

I can easily enter letters right now for instance

Comment: Answer : RadTextBox is simply not supported. I need to use asp textbox.

Comment: then please add your answer and accept it for the further visitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the RadInputManager is to convert standard controls to RadControls at runtime. Therefore, you should either have the `RadInputManager` OR the `RadTextBox`, but you don't need both.

You can achieve the HH:MM functionality you want with either way you choose.  For example:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadTextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
    id="txtValidator"
    runat="server"
    Display="Dynamic"
    ErrorMessage="Please, enter valid time in HH:MM format."
    ValidationExpression="^((?<Hour>[0-9]{1,2})[.:](?=[0-9]{2}))?(?<Minute>[0-9]{1,2})$"
    ControlToValidate="RadTextBox1">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" />
```

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-textbox-limiting-allowable-values.html